# reset multiple form fields with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code to reset a form field using a checkbox with AngularJS.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.test" ng-disabled="data.check">

<input type="checkbox" 
ng-change="data.test = data.check ? '' : data.test"
ng-model="data.check" 
value="one">
```

How would I use this code to reset multiple form fields?

Thanks,

John

Comment: you want to reset the form fields when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: yes, the code works above but just on a single field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data in separate array and validator in another variable

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.test" ng-disabled="clear.check">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.test_another" ng-disabled="clear.check">

<input type="checkbox" ng-change="data = clear.check ? {} : data"
ng-model="clear.check" value="one">
```

Once you want to reset the form data, you can directly assign empty array set to form data array

Comment: I tried this code and it did not work. Was there something else I needed to add other than the above?

Comment: its working fine for me, check my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/wrV9vZMdFqtlqtvLxWAA

Comment: It works! Not sure what I was doing wrong but it's working fine now.

Comment: Only problem I have now is that checked="checked" does not work on the checkbox. It looks like it's ng-model="clear.check" causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$setPristine()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) for resetting the field state.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">

    <input type="text" ng-model="data.test" ng-disabled="data.check">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.test2" ng-disabled="data.check">
    <input type="checkbox" 
    ng-change="reset()"
    ng-model="data.check" 
    value="one">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.resetForm = function() {
    $scope.data = {
        "test": "",
        "test2": ""
    };
    // 'myForm' is the name of the <form> tag.
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and get a - Can't find variable: $scope error.